# How to save photo from Camera Android

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, photo, image

Edit: I found out the problem is in the onPreviewFrame function:

```
@Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        if (frameCount == 0) {
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else if (frameCount % 100 == 0) {
            Log.e("FPS", 1000 * frameCount
                    / (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "");
        }
        frameCount++;
        Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        try {
            temp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, new FileOutputStream(new File("/sdcard/"+frameCount+".jpg")));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        camera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
    }
```

If I remove all the code related to Bitmap then the program can take a picture without any error. How can I save both frame images and the better image produced with Camera.takePicture?
I tried to save photo from camera when a button is touched and start another activity to edit the photo.

```
mTakePic.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    mTakePic.setImageDrawable(takePicDown);
                    mCamera.takePicture(new ShutterCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onShutter() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    }, null, new PictureCallback() {


                        @Override
                        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] yuv, Camera camera) {
                            Intent editImage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditActivity.class);

                            if(savePhoto != null) {
                                try {
                                    savePhoto.get();
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            savePhoto = new SavePhotoTask();
                            savePhoto.execute(yuv);

//                          releaseCamera();
                            startActivity(editImage);
                        }
                    });
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    mTakePic.setImageDrawable(takePicUp);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Sometimes it runs smoothly without error but most times it ends up an error and I have to restart my phone to get the camera working again. I used a SurfaceView for previewing camera frame.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Sorry, I mistook the question, I thought you were linking the crash you mentioned to the SavePhotoTask.  Here's how you can save a photo from your `PictureCallback`

The first argument to `onPictureTaken` is a byte array that contains the image.  Simply writing it out to a file is the best way I've found to save the image.  Something like this...

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("path/to/image");
out.write(data, 0, data.length);
out.close();
```

Where "data" is the first arg from `onPictureTaken`.  This same technique should work to save each frame in `onPreviewFrame` but I've never tried this so I can't be sure.  It seems like you have the idea of putting this operation on a separate thread, which is excellent and I'd continue exploring that option.  I'd avoid using a Bitmap however, as this will take time and resources, and could lead to OOM errors if you're converting many frames concurrently and have all those Bitmaps in memory.

---

Once you make the call to `Camera.open()`, your app is putting a lock on the camera and blocking any other applications (including subsequent instances of your own application) from using it.  A call must be made to `Camera.release()` when your application is done or the camera will remain locked until, as you've noted, the phone is restarted.  [The dev docs for the Camera has a good checklist to follow at the top in order to ensure the class gets used correctly.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html)

I've had success making the call to `Camera.open()` in `onResume()` and `Camera.release()` in `onPause()`.  To keep things smooth and bug free, you may want to manage your start and stop preview at these points as well.

Comment: Thank you @MattDavis, but it's not the answer for my question. I edited the question, please take a look at it

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how to save, let me know if it helps.